# Login into slack and list my workspaces

Tags: slack

I must be doing something real dumb because this doesn't make sense to me.

I just want to login to slack and get a list of all my workspaces I joined.

But slack only lets you log directly into a slack workspace.

You can get a list of your workspaces, but you have to enter your email and are sent a one time use link that brings you to a page that lists all your workspaces.

I don't get it, why cant I just have a page I can bookmark that lists all my workspaces and login into it with my slack username/pass?

Comment: You can sign into mutliple workspaces by clicking on your name in the top left hand corner. It will open a menu and there is an option at the bottom that says `Sign in to another work space ...` From there you can log into another workspace, and it will add tabs to the side bar so you can quickly switch between workspaces.

Comment: the other workspaces already need to be added. If you do "Find your slack workspace" you need to do the email single use link thing

Comment: ^ the above comments should probably be answers...

Answer (score 3):

It's remarkably confusing to add all of your workspaces when setting up a new device, and especially my OSX desktop client. This [guidance from Slack about finding your workspace URL](https://slack.com/help/articles/221769328-Locate-your-Slack-URL) helped me learn to do it more efficiently (as of June, 2020):

1. From your browser, head to [Your Workspaces on Slack](https://slack.com/your-workspaces)
2. Enter your email address and click Confirm.
3. Check your email, then select Confirm Email Address. The email will say something like:

> Once you've confirmed that XXX@YYY is your email address, we’ll help you find your Slack workspaces.

5. From the Your Workspaces page, go through each workspace and select "Launch" and then confirm that you want to use your Slack app if/when you get a modal. That should result in all of your workspaces being efficiently added to the UI in your Slack app.